# Google Apps Script, OAuth2, and Salesforce

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, salesforce

I am trying to get this demo working: [Google Apps Script / Salesforce.com](https://github.com/entaq/GoogleAppsScript/tree/master/Salesforce.com)

I have watched the linked video several times, searched and search for hours for a solution, but I continue to get the same error as others:

```html
error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=redirect_uri%20must%20match%20configuration
```

Questions: 
1) Do we still need to change the callback url from "script" to "docs" when the using a script bound to a spreadsheet? I have tried it both ways.

2)Do I need to change endpoint urls because of my salesforce having a custom domain in the form of mycompany.cloudforce.com ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you show me your redirect URI? It looks something like 'http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback' (when testing locally) in your Google Dev Console.

Comment: That code and video are a bit old, not sure if everything still works there. You might want to try this sample instead: https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/samples/Salesforce.gs

Comment: So I opened the Developer Tools in Chrome, went to the Console tab, ran the code, got the error message mentioned previously, and what I got was "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)" along with a link: https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=XXX&redirect_uri=https://script.google.com/a/XXX.com/macros/s/XXX/exec (replaced my info with XXX)

Comment: Eric, I also tried that code, and received the same exact error.

Comment: the gsuitedevs code gives me this URL https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?client_id=XXX.XXX&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fmacros%2Fd%2FXXX%2Fusercallback&state=XXX&scope=Google_Apps_Script%20refresh_token

Answer (score 0):

Success! I was able to successfully get past this hurdle...got to the login page.

the function

```html
logRedirectUri()
```

in the gsuitedevs code gsave me the correct callback URI